# can I create a dictionary with the value is a list

Tags: kdb

I try to create a dictionary with the value is a list. the list is generated based on the key. For example, add 1 to the key and repeat 100 times.

```
0| 1 1 ...1 //a list with 100 "1" which is key(0)+1
1| 2 2 ...2
2| 3 3 ...3
3| 4 4 ...4
```

Can I do this in KDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{[lst;n]til[n]!lst+/:til n}[100#1;4]
```

This function accepts the list and the number n you wish to go too. the /: is an adverb each-right which in this case is added each rhs parameter to the lhs parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
{y#'1+til[x]!til x}[4;100]
```

As a rule of thumb, whenever function is applied to dictionary in Q, it is applied to its list of values. Assuming this, function `y'#` applied to dictionary `0 1 2 ... ! 1 2 3 ...` above turns its values to lists of constants.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to specify the keys (non-incremental for example):

```
{x!100#/:1+x:(),x}0 4 6
```

And you could of course make the `100` and `1` variables too